# Why does a mutable iterator need a mutable reference when passed to a function?

Tags: rust, immutability, mutability

Why do all methods in a chain of calls except the last need a mutable reference to a mutable iterator?

My intention is to change the internal state of the iterator (`...: &mut std::slice::Iter<u8>`), not the pointer/reference itself (`mut it: ...`). My intuition is built on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682542/407981).

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut it = v.iter();

    match it.next() {
        Some(v) => {
            fun1(&mut it);
            println!("{:?}", v);
        }
        None => (),
    }
}

fn fun1(mut it: &mut std::slice::Iter<u8>) {
    //  ^-- why mut?
    match it.next() {
        Some(v) => {
            fun2(&mut it);
            println!("{:?}", v);
        }
        None => (),
    }
}

fn fun2(it: &mut std::slice::Iter<u8>) {
    //  ^-- not needed
    match it.next() {
        Some(v) => {
            println!("{:?}", v);
        }
        None => (),
    }
}
```

When I remove this `mut`, I get this error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `it` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:18
   |
14 | fn fun1(it: &mut std::slice::Iter<u8>) {
   |         -- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut it`
...
18 |             fun2(&mut it);
   |                  ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Comment: You shouldn't be making a reference to the reference at all: `fun2(it)`. Does adding `mut` actually make it compile?

Comment: Yes, weird, but it compile with `mut` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f29c777522ece855488d6c97882cd0ce). I was more interested of this specific, strange "reference collapsing mechanic" (_deref coercions_?), rather what is proper why to do this. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034912/how-do-i-recursively-pass-a-mutable-reference/38034953#38034953) is probably what I was looking for. Thanks.